# Cохранение активити при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android

У меня есть три кнопки в приложении и 3 textview со счетчиком. При нажатии на кнопку tv записывает число в порядке возрастания, в зависимости от кол-ва нажатий.
А при повороте устройства, всё сбрасывается и активити пересоздается. Помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю как сохранить текущую информацию активити?

```
public class MoxyMainActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity
        implements MoxyExampleView, View.OnClickListener {

    @InjectPresenter
    Presenter presenter;

    private Button btnCounter1;
    private Button btnCounter2;
    private Button btnCounter3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnCounter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCounter1);
        btnCounter2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCounter2);
        btnCounter3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCounter3);
        btnCounter1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCounter2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCounter3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("key", "value");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        presenter.buttonClick(v.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void setButtonText(int btnIndex, int value) {
        switch (btnIndex) {
            case 1:
                btnCounter1.setText("Количество = " + value);
                break;
            case 2:
                btnCounter2.setText("Количество = " + value);
                break;
            case 3:
                btnCounter3.setText("Количество = " + value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCounter1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Количество = 0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCounter2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Количество = 0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCounter3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Количество = 0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того кода, что вы предоставили - получается примерно так:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Тут сохраняем в outState данные
    outState.putInt("counter1",valueCounter1);
    outState.putInt("counter2",valueCounter2);
    outState.putInt("counter3",valueCounter3);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // А тут восстанавливаем данные
    setButtonText(R.id.btnCounter1,savedInstanceState.getInt("counter1",0));
    setButtonText(R.id.btnCounter2,savedInstanceState.getInt("counter2",0));
    setButtonText(R.id.btnCounter3,savedInstanceState.getInt("counter3",0));
}
```

А дальше уже сами делайте как угодно.

Comment: Принцип понял, большое спасибо за объяснение. Но почему-то это ничего не дало, сейчас разбираюсь почему.